# WinSCP removes line breaks on upload

Tags: file-upload, line-breaks, winscp

I use WinSCP as ftp client and i have the transfer set to binary. I also use Notepad++ as editor.

Hovewer every file i upload, is stripped of all line breaks.

```
<?php
// this is a comment
echo 'this is an echo';
?>
```

Gets turned into

```
<?php // this is a comment echo 'this is an echo'; ?>
```

Outputting nothing beacause it is interpreted as comment.

Do I have to set something else to upload files without any problem?

Comment: *"Gets turned into"*: How do you check that?

Comment: Just viewing the code online ( Ctrl + U )

Comment: If you can "view the code online", your PHP code is not interpreted at all. You cannot normally see a PHP code in a webbrowser. The webbrowser should get only the resulting HTML code. Your problem is completely different than what you describe.

Comment: My php code has also html inside. What i described was an example of what i get once the file is uploaded, that is html code stripped of all line breaks :)

Comment: Well, that involves yet more software on the way (web server and web browser at least). Let stick with the simple path first. So again, how do you check that PHP file turns to `<?php // this is a comment echo 'this is an echo'; ?>`?

Answer (score 0):

With FTP protocol, WinSCP never modifies line endings itself.

So it's either your editor or the FTP server.

1. Find a local temporary copy of the file you have opened in Notepad++. Open it in a binary viewer/editor and check, if the line-end characters are present.
2. Check if Ascii/Text or Binary mode is used for the upload. WinSCP defaults to Binary mode. But you may have configured it to use Ascii/Text mode. While this should not remove the line endings, there maybe some issue with FTP server. Forcing (default) Binary mode may help.
3. Download the edited file using Binary mode and open it in binary editor/viewer and check if the line-end characters are present. Or do binary compare against the local temporary copy. They should be binary identical, if the Binary mode was used for upload.